# Error when enqueuing buffer from callback Wit.ai SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, wit.ai

I'm new to iOS and I'm writing my first application using wit.ai SDK (following this guide https://wit.ai/docs/ios/3.1.1/quickstart).

I can run my app and send a command (that I'll find in my wit.ai inbox) but then the app craches.

Here is my code:

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> 
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Wit/Wit.h>

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
[Wit sharedInstance].accessToken = @"ASW7RE57SOSZLTNBAM6HQ53QAWXSROOI";
[Wit sharedInstance].detectSpeechStop = WITVadConfigDetectSpeechStop;
// Override point for customization after application launch.
return YES;
}
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Wit/Wit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <WitDelegate>


@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController {
    UILabel *labelView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // set the WitDelegate object
    [Wit sharedInstance].delegate = self;

    // create the button
    CGRect screen = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    CGFloat w = 100;
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(screen.size.width/2 - w/2, 60, w, 100);

    WITMicButton* witButton = [[WITMicButton alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    [self.view addSubview:witButton];

    // create the label
    labelView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, screen.size.width, 50)];
    labelView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [self.view addSubview:labelView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)witDidGraspIntent:(NSArray *)outcomes entities:(NSDictionary *)entities body:(NSString *)body error:(NSError*)e {
    if (e) {
        NSLog(@"[Wit] error: %@", [e localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }
    NSDictionary *firstOutcome = [outcomes objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *intent = [firstOutcome objectForKey:@"intent"];

    labelView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"intent = %@", intent];

    [self.view addSubview:labelView];
}

@end
```

Here are the errors I get:

2015-01-12 22:24:21.419 FirstApp[11199:775307] WITVad init
2015-01-12 22:24:27.789 FirstApp[11199:775513] Error when enqueuing buffer from callback: -66632
2015-01-12 22:24:27.790 FirstApp[11199:775513] Error when enqueuing buffer from callback: -66632
2015-01-12 22:24:27.790 FirstApp[11199:775513] Error when enqueuing buffer from callback: -66632
2015-01-12 22:24:27.790 FirstApp[11199:775513] Error when enqueuing buffer from callback: -66632
2015-01-12 22:24:27.790 FirstApp[11199:775513] Error when enqueuing buffer from callback: -66632
2015-01-12 22:24:36.442 FirstApp[11199:775307] -[**NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8da0c60c30
2015-01-12 22:24:36.755 FirstApp[11199:775307] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8da0c60c30'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105bd0f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010548fbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105bd804d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105b3027c ___forwarding_** + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105b2fe18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   FirstApp                            0x00000001034778bd -[ViewController witDidGraspIntent:entities:body:error:] + 253
    6   FirstApp                            0x000000010347a705 -[Wit processMessage:] + 535
    7   FirstApp                            0x000000010347a3a2 -[Wit gotResponse:error:] + 67
    8   FirstApp                            0x000000010347a3f3 -[Wit gotResponse:error:customData:] + 62
    9   FirstApp                            0x0000000103478549 -[WITRecordingSession gotResponse:error:] + 196
    10  FirstApp                            0x000000010347b726 **39-[WITUploader startRequestWithContext:]_block_invoke + 708
    11  CFNetwork                           0x0000000106781935 __67+[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_2 + 155
    12  Foundation                          0x000000010360201f __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 7
    13  Foundation                          0x0000000103541db2 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 98
    14  Foundation                          0x0000000103524384 -[**NSOperationInternal _start:] + 645
    15  Foundation                          0x0000000103523f93 __NSOQSchedule_f + 184
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106eec7f4 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106ed58fb _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 949
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105b38fe9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 9
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105afbeeb __CFRunLoopRun + 2043
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105afb486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000107f739f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    22  UIKit                               0x00000001039d2420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    23  FirstApp                            0x0000000103477e53 main + 115
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000106f21145 start + 1
    25  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Thanks for your help.

Comment: 1. View->Navigators->Show breakpoint navigator. In left bottom side click at + and chose Add Exception Breakpoint. Now just enable breakpoints and run your program. You will see where is crash.
2. Additionaly you can use zombie-object: project scheme choose edit scheme, in appear window choose Diagnostics and enable checkbox Enable Zombie Objects. I think it will show you where is crash and you will easy fix it.